# Forms Authenticated MVC application - Ajax calls are always unauthroized

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create an MVC application with Forms Authentication. When the application is hosted in IIS and build from Visual Studio, everything works fine. When I tried to Publish and deploy to the same server, I see that all ajax calls fail. Further debugging reveals that the ajax calls return the Login page. However, other controller calls which load normal views work fine, implying the user is still Authenticated. Can anyone tell me whats going on?

Comment: Just a random guess - Maybe you are using a session which have stored values for login and password?

Comment: Nope, I was calling a separate domain which did not have the authentication cookie.